# Access to system icons in QT / QML

Tags: android, ios, qt, qml, icons

When developing native apps for iOS, the iOS SDK features something like:

```
[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd ...] autorelease];
```

Those are native icons OS icons, and there are [several of them](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/system-icons/). I have not yet developed any android apps, but I guess android SDK offers similar functionality.

Now the question is, when developing cross-platform apps using QT, is it possible to reference those native system icons in QT/QML?

It would be really great to use those standard system icons, to retain a native feeling in the app, rather than providing custom app icons for standard use cases.

Comment: Not sure but I think you might be looking for [`QStyle::standardIcon`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#standardIcon).

Comment: How would I use those in QML?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use QML.  Perhaps someone else can comment.  You might want to look at [this post](https://forum.qt.io/topic/69888/can-qapplication-style-standardicon-be-used-on-a-qml-button-do-2-0-buttons-even-support-icons).

Answer (score 0):

Following up on G.M.'s comment I've used a `QQuickImageProvider`, don't know if this works for Android. Unfortunately it uses a `QApplication` instead of a `QGuiApplication` otherwise it isn't possible to get the `QStyle` via `style()`. Therefor `widgets` needs to be added as a library.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>
#include <QStyle>

class StandardIconProvider : public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
    StandardIconProvider(QStyle *style)
        : QQuickImageProvider(Pixmap)
        , m_style(style)
    {}

    QPixmap requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize) override
    {
        Q_UNUSED(size)
        static const auto metaobject = QMetaEnum::fromType<QStyle::StandardPixmap>();
        const int value = metaobject.keyToValue(id.toLatin1());
        QIcon icon = m_style->standardIcon(static_cast<QStyle::StandardPixmap>(value));
        return icon.pixmap(requestedSize);
    }

    QStyle *m_style;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.addImageProvider(QLatin1String("standardicons"), new StandardIconProvider(app.style()));

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Standard Icon Provider demo")

    component Icon: Image {
        width: 64
        height: 64
        sourceSize: Qt.size(64, 64)
    }

    Grid {
        columns: 3
        rows: 3
        spacing: 10
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Icon { source: "image://standardicons/SP_TrashIcon" }
        Icon { source: "image://standardicons/SP_MessageBoxCritical" }
        Icon { source: "image://standardicons/SP_DirHomeIcon" }
        Icon { source: "image://standardicons/SP_DirClosedIcon" }
        Icon { source: "image://standardicons/SP_ArrowUp" }
        Icon { source: "image://standardicons/SP_DialogHelpButton" }
        Icon { source: "image://standardicons/SP_BrowserStop" }
        Icon { source: "image://standardicons/SP_FileLinkIcon" }
        Icon { source: "image://standardicons/SP_DialogSaveButton" }
    }
}
```

[image]